# How to achieve HTTPContext.RewritePath() in Page_Load or Page_Init event

Tags: url-rewriting, httpcontext

I am currently working on a URL Rewriting project. I have seen most of the examples where context.RewritePath() is used in either an HTTPModule or a Global.asax. I just need to know whether this can be acheieved in any of the Page level events like PreInit, Init or Load ?

I tried it in all the above events but does not seem to be working.

Can some one please advice.